# ionic build android error when using cordova build --release android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build an Ionic project on EC2 but after everything has been installed, I got a build failure error when running:

```
cordova build --release android
```

Here is the error message I have received:

```
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processReleaseResources'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/ec2-user/android/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.093 secs
```

I have inspected the folder and I can find the file it's complaining about. So not really sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I need to install 32 bit glibc to execute 64 bit binaries, and running this solved the issue for me.

yum install zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 libgcc.i686